# Un div Absolute, me tapa un div Fixed

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Pagina de ejemplo
  </title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="cabecera">
  <p class="titulo" id="inicio"></p>
  <p class="inicio"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#inicio" class="enlace">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contacto" class="enlace">Contacto</a></li>
  <li><a href="#articulos" class="enlace">Articulos</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div  class="articulos" id="articulos">
  
  </div>
  <div class="contacto" id="contacto">
  <p>Contacto</p>
   <form class="formulario" action="mailto:tarea2@foc.es" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="nombre"> <br/>
    <label for="apellidos">Apellidos:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="apellidos"> <br/>
    <label for="email">email:</label> 
    <input type="email" name="email"> <br/>
    <label for="mensaje">Mensaje:</label> 
    <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Escriba su mensaje..."></textarea> </br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
   </form>
  </div>
  <div class="pie">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Buenas, resulta que maquetando una pagina, quiero dejar el menu arriba fijo, en la hoja de estilos es un position Fixed, abajo tengo como una descripcion, y abajo unos articulos. Los dos los tengo en position absolute. Al bajar el scroll, el menu queda fijo, con la descripcion no pasa nada, pero al llegar a los articulos, este lo tapa. Os paso el codigo:

```
.menu {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    height:10%;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:auto;
    background-color:yellow;
    visibility:visible;
}
.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li {
  float:left; 
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align:center;
  margin:20px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.cabecera {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    right: 0;
    top:10%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: auto;
    background-color:green;
    text-align:center;
}
.articulos{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:80%;
    right: 0;
    top:30%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: auto;
    background-color:gray;
    text-align:center;
}
img {
    width:400px;
    height:220px;
    border-radius:25px;
}
.coche1{
    position:absolute;
    left:10%;
}
.coche2{
    position:absolute;
    right:10%;
}
.coche3{
    position:absolute;
    left:10%;
    top:300%;
}
.coche4{
    position:absolute;
    right:10%;
    top:300%;
}
.pie {
    height:700px;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: En cuestión de diseño, siempre provee también el HTML. Edita tu pregunta y añádelo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloca la propiedad **z-index** al div fixed, tal que así:

```
.menu {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    height:10%;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:auto;
    background-color:yellow;
    visibility:visible;
    z-index: 999;

}
```

Si ves que sigue sucediendo, añade a los divs absolute un **z-index** inferior.

Comment: Si, me funciono, muchas gracias XD

Comment: De nada @BorjaCámara, marca mi mensaje como respuesta de tu duda. Gracias.